# Why does string (const char* s, size_t pos, size_t len = npos) work?

Tags: c++, string

It's not listed explicitly in std::string [constructor doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), (**EDIT:** folks here says I should cite actual [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) not cplusplus.com) but apparently it works. That means it's like the equivalent of `strncpy`, isn't it?

Does it work because it implicitly first initializes another `std::string` object that's a copy of the `const char* string` passed in? Does it mean it does extra work of copying the entire string though, even if it eventually only extracts a certain length of substring?

Also it seems such construction is *kind of* like `string (const char* s+pos, size_t len)` except the reference says here if len is greater than string length, it causes `undefined behavior`; yet in `string (const char* s, size_t pos, size_t len = npos)` if len is longer passed null terminator it's just fine. Presumably that's because, I guess, this internally is dealing with stuff on cpp string object level and the former is messing with pointers.

And why doesn't that behavior gets listed in c++ reference doc?

My guess is it's a kind of weird combination of internally copy to `std::string` object and then apply `string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos)` to it, so it's not considered "standard". That said, I find this super useful, when I have to take input as `char*`, while I pretty much don't care about copying the entire string once, yet I can get away doing any `malloc` and `strncpy` and neither do I want to write code to branch out in making sure size limit len doesn't go out of bound.

Comment: Hey 2 downvotes 5 mins after the question created, and no comment for explanation?

Comment: I downvoted, because you would spend less time testing it than writing the question.

Comment: @dyukha What do you even mean? I of course tested it because it freaking works. Not just compiles, but prints out the expected result.

Comment: `Does it mean it does extra work of copying the entire string though, even if it eventually only extracts a certain length of substring?`

Comment: @dyukha A lot of things "work" in C++ that aren't in spec.  The poster asks a valid question.  Is it UB?  Is it an extension?  Do you know?

Comment: @dyukha and what exactly is the problem with the quoted part of the question? It's an internal mechanism thing, and how's that quicker to test out than asking here?

Comment: It's the thing you are interested in. It can be tested trivially: create a huge string and call the method on its tiny substring, measure time. It's like total 10 lines of code, with all includes.

Comment: @dyukha Suppose I can do that but it's still a "guess" on why things work particularly that way. I don't see this question itself worth downvoting as I believe there's more value in clarifying the cpp specs, getting some insights from folks well versed in cpp, than just testing on one machine/OS to get the empirical behavior. And giving visibility for others encountering similar question on Internet.

Comment: It's a "guess" with 99.99% probability. "Empirical behavior" point is valid (though only in the sense that different implementations may have a different set of constructors).

Comment: @dyukha Testing is not a great way of learning C++. Mostly because UB exists, if something works you still don't know that it isn't a coincidence.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Don't see how UB can happen here. It's solely a matter of casting.

Comment: @dyukha Yeah, but that's because you know that. If you don't know it, testing it yourself doesn't help. C++, unlike some other languages, cannot be reliably learned by trial and error.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Well, of course you should be careful about what you test. It's usually predictable when UB can arise (not always, but in this case there were no risk, even without knowing the answer).

Comment: In this case, that's true, but @thc's comment applies. You can't tell what is an implementation detail and what is required without researching it. The goal of my comment was to express that "test it" is pretty much never the right way to learn about C++ as a language. This is in response to *"you would spend less time testing it than writing the question"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because of the presence of constructor:

```
std::basic_string( const basic_string& other, 
                   size_type pos, 
                   size_type count = std::basic_string::npos,
                   const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

`const char *` is implicitly convertible to `std::basic_string`, so the above constructor is called after said conversion when you write (for example) `std::string s {"abc", 1, 2};`

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b3mYuHZagR4zereH)

To address your question of efficiency, the implicit conversion from `char *` to `std::basic_string` involves construction of a temporary, so yes, the string is copied.

Comment: Thanks that's pretty much what I thought. I guess I was just bit stuck in, thinking cpp reference is some kind of "standard", but no yeah it's just a guidebook, so I should connect the dots myself :-)

Comment: @Superziyi cppreference is fairly good. In the question you linked to cplusplus.com which is considered rubbish around here

Comment: @M.M lol that's good to know, thanks. To be fair cppreference doesn't list the exact constructor as well but points taken https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @Superziyi "*cppreference doesn't list the exact constructor as well*" - yes, it does mention the constructor Paul pointed out. Look again more closely.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No it doesn't. Which one? I'm not talking about (3). The only mention of char* is (4) and (5)